# Character Encoding Detection Algorithm

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm looking for a way to detect character sets within documents.  I've been reading the Mozilla character set detection implementation here:

[Universal Charset Detection](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html)

I've also found a Java implementation of this called jCharDet:

[JCharDet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/)

Both of these are based on research carried out using a set of static data.  What I'm wondering is whether anybody has used any other implementation successfully and if so what?  Did you roll your own approach and if so what was the algorithm you used to detect the character set?

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not looking for a list of existing approaches via Google, nor am I looking for a link to the Joel Spolsky article - just to clarify : )

**UPDATE:** I did a bunch of research into this and ended up finding a framework called cpdetector that uses a pluggable approach to character detection, see:

[CPDetector](http://cpdetector.sourceforge.net/)

This provides BOM, chardet (Mozilla approach) and ASCII detection plugins.  It's also very easy to write your own.  There's also another framework, which provides much better character detection that the Mozilla approach/jchardet etc...

[ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/)

It's quite easy to write your own plugin for cpdetector that uses this framework to provide a more accurate character encoding detection algorithm.  It works better than the Mozilla approach.

Comment: It's a tough problem. Thanks for the great links from your own research.

Comment: There is one famous case of this: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx

Comment: Yep, been over the notepad issue, I'll revise my post with my research once I'm done and complete, some interesting stuff...

Comment: There is another porting in Java: https://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/

Comment: juniversalchardet looks like it hasn't been updated in 6 years; ICU was updated earlier this year.

Comment: Apache tika seems to have something. Not tested yet https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/CharsetDetector.java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Years ago we had character set detection for a mail application, and we rolled our own. The mail app was actually a WAP application, and the phone expected UTF-8. There were several steps:

**Universal**

We could easily detect if text was UTF-8, as there is a specific bit pattern in the top bits of bytes 2/3/etc. Once you found that pattern repeated a certain number of times you could be certain it was UTF-8.

If the file begins with a UTF-16 byte order mark, you can probably assume the rest of the text is that encoding. Otherwise, detecting UTF-16 isn't nearly as easy as UTF-8, unless you can detect the surrogate pairs pattern: but the use of surrogate pairs is rare, so that doesn't usually work. UTF-32 is similar, except there are no surrogate pairs to detect.

**Regional detection**

Next we would assume the reader was in a certain region. For instance, if the user was seeing the UI localized in Japanese, we could then attempt detection of the three main Japanese encodings. ISO-2022-JP is again east to detect with the escape sequences. If that fails, determining the difference between EUC-JP and Shift-JIS is not as straightforward. It's more likely that a user would receive Shift-JIS text, but there were characters in EUC-JP that didn't exist in Shift-JIS, and vice-versa, so sometimes you could get a good match.

The same procedure was used for Chinese encodings and other regions.

**User's choice**

If these didn't provide satisfactory results, the user must manually choose an encoding.

Comment: I assume that the systems you reference in the links use similar strategies to those I described, but hopefully sharing our experience will be helpful.

Comment: UTF-32 is very easy to detect, due to the restriction on the code point range.  A valid UTF-32 code unit will always fit the pattern 00 {0x|10} xx xx (for BE) or xx xx {0x|10} 00 (for LE).

Comment: @JaredOberhaus could you please show some java code about the first step ? also, how would you find the items of the correct group of encodings for the second step?

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly what you asked for, but I noticed that the [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) includes a [CharsetDetector](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html) class.