# How to find encodng of a file programatically?

Tags: java, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

How to identify the encoding of a input file by using JAVA?

Comment: what kind of encoding? is it an image file, text file (unicode, multi-byte code page, office document?)

Comment: I assume he means character encoding (i.e. the codepage) of a text file.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774075/character-encoding-detection-algorithm

Comment: If at all possible, get all the help you can from the origin of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting correct encoding of a given text is not exact science. All above software are approximations.